# How to drag an object from point A to B in DirectX with less frustration

Tags: path, scroll, directx, drag, segment

I have to drag an object from point A to B like the scroll bar does it in Windows, the problem here is that the A and B does not have neither X or Y the same, so the movement is horizontal and vertical at the same time - diagonal.

I did came up with an simple algorithm that based on the cursor position in a frame, updates the position of the object to be dragged. But for that I have to make the cursorX=objectX, and than calculate the objectY, or vice-versa. This makes the movement "less frustrating" for horizontal movement or vertical, respectively. So if the diagonal is close to the horizontal line,  the part with cursorX=objectX makes it a better choice than with cursorY=objectY, and for the diagonal close to a vertical line  " cursorY=objectY" makes it a better choice that the other one. The problem here is that I have to use a an general algorithm for both type of diagonals cause I have [star polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon) and the object has to be able to move from any corner to any corner.

Here is the code I wrote, but it doesn't seems to move "right" as to be visual right and less frustrating for the user, I hope it will make more sens for the question. What I did at the end, used both methods as for vertical movement and for horizontal and devided by 2, so everybody is happy, bu that didn't do the trick:

```
//calculating with x priority
D3DXVECTOR2 resultPosX;

resultPosX.x=nextMousePos.x;

//firstCornerPos and secondCornerPos are the edges of a segment 
//on wich the object has to move
resultPosX.y=prevObjPos.y+(nextMousePos.x-prevObjPos.x)*(secondCornerPos.y-firstCornerPos.y)/(secondCornerPos.x-firstCornerPos.x);

//calculating with y priority
D3DXVECTOR2 resultPosY;

resultPosY.y=nextMousePos.y;

resultPosY.x=prevObjPos.x+(nextMousePos.y-prevObjPos.y)*(secondCornerPos.x-firstCornerPos.x)/(secondCornerPos.y-firstCornerPos.y);

//calculating the average result
resultPos.x=(resultPosX.x+resultPosY.x)/2;
resultPos.y=(resultPosX.y+resultPosY.y)/2;
```

Comment: Have you ever find your solution on this issue?

Comment: I believe aIt was long time ago, but I believe in the end I used the algorithm that I mention in the question.